# @capacitor/status-bar iOS: Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: not implemented

Tags: ios, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have a problem with the *@capacitor/status-bar* plugin from Capacitor.
On the platform iOS, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: not implemented

Already importing the plugin causes the error.

```
import { StatusBar, Style } from '@capacitor/status-bar';
...
const hideStatusBar = async () => {
    await StatusBar.hide();
};
```

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints.

The Version of Capacitor and Plugins are the following:

> Capacitor: 3.2.4
> Capacitor plugins for iOS:
>  @capacitor/device@1.0.2
>  @capacitor/geolocation@1.1.0
>  @capacitor/splash-screen@1.1.2
> ** @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.3**
> Cordova plugin for ios:
>  cordova-sqlite-storage@6.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

import { Plugins, PluginRegistry, Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

const { SplashScreen, StatusBar }: PluginRegistry = Plugins;

if (Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('StatusBar')) { StatusBar.show() };

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer pointed me the right way. Just using StatusBar.show() did the trick. Some Errors are too easy to see. Have a nice weekend.